# Specific graph in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How can i do something like this? (Ofc, use highcharts)
http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/3439/temp1a.png
I have 2 (may be better use 3) axis with data and some scale that calculates the efficiency of the some parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to play around with the gauge type.

You can probably get a good deal of info on how to proceed from the VU meter example:

http://highcharts.com/demo/gauge-vu-meter